# Get JSON data with Ajax call from external URL

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to call a web service with POST method this is the url

https://innovation.spa.uvm.mx:22580/webs-images/rest/imagx

i modified the url because of privacy of the company where i work, this  is a example url but the original url has the same structure

I have done it in POSTMAN with this JSON string:

```
{
"personid" : "20369"
}
```

in POSTMAN it works fine i get a 200 OK status.

But in my ajax call i get a 500 error. net::ERR_ABORTED 500 Error.
 This is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://innovation.spa.uvm.mx:22580/webs-images/rest/imagx",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  data: JSON.stringify({
    "personid" : "20369"
  }),      
  success: function(result){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
  },
  error: function(exception){
    alert("Error" + exception);
  }
});
```

Comment: You seams to be using `jsonp` but never specify a callback to use. If you don't need `jsonp`, try to remove the option.

Comment: @Nicolas — jQuery will dynamically generate the callback portion of the URL.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't making a POST request, you are making a GET request.

JSONP can't make POST requests due to [the way it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-and-why-was-it-created).

Presumably the webservice expects a POST request and errors because it isn't getting one.

---

Possibly you slapped `jsonp` in there in an effort to circumvent [the Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). JSONP only does that if the web service you are making the request to **explicitly** supports JSONP (which it shouldn't these days because we have CORS (which gives a lot more control and doesn't have the security risks inherent in JSONP) now).

---

Even if you remove the `jsonp`, you are claiming `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` but the value of `data` *isn't JSON*. If you pass an object to `data` then jQuery with URL encode it. If you want to send JSON you need to encode it yourself with `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: why im making  GET? im using jsonp because is a external url and if i dont use it i get this: has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: @AlexPalacios — You are making a GET request for the reason I mentioned in the second paragraph of this answer.

Comment: @AlexPalacios — The fourth paragraph of this answer said it was probably because you were trying to bypass the same origin policy. You can't do that that way. The server has to grant you permission.